# Write putObject to S3 directly from HTTP API in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, aws-http-api

My intention is to create an HTTP API on Amazon API Gateway that writes a file to S3 using the PutObject action via the S3 API (without calling Lambda in between). This is the PutObject request syntax: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax

I'm not sure if this is technically possible and I'm getting a 403 Forbidden: ForbiddenException response in Postman.

So far I have:

1. Created the S3 bucket (with CORS configured)
2. Created the HTTP API in API Gateway (with CORS configured), with a 'putObject' POST action
3. Configured an integration on the HTTP API to https://[s3-bucket-name].s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
4. Create a Postman request to the HTTP API 'invoke URL', with 'Host' and 'x-apigw-api-id' set on the headers

The ForbiddenException obviously indicates a permission issue, either on the HTTP API or the S3 API behind it. I did configure a Cloudwatch Log Group on the HTTP API, which is showing no entries, so it seems that it's an HTTP API access issue.

I also suspect that I need to add Parameter Mappings to the HTTP API to pass in all of the necessary headers to the S3 putObject action.

My questions are:

1. Is this type of HTTP API integration direct to S3 possible?
2. What is the likely cause of the 403 Forbidden response from the service?
3. Would I use 'Append' Parameter Mappings in the HTTP API integration configuration to add the standard S3 API parameters (and avoid exposing them to the client)?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this myself. Answers to my own questions:

**Is this type of HTTP API integration direct to S3 possible?**

Yes. On my HTTP API I used an HTTP PUT integration that points to the S3 service endpoint (including the bucket name in the endpoint is incorrect).

**What is the likely cause of the 403 Forbidden response from the service?**

I didn't get the request working from Postman, however, when I made the request from the browser it worked. I had to create a Blob in Javascript before sending it as a request via navigator.beacon() to the HTTP API endpoint URL.

**Would I use 'Append' Parameter Mappings in the HTTP API integration configuration to add the standard S3 API parameters (and avoid exposing them to the client)?**

I did have to use Parameter Mappings to get the S3 PutObject request to work from API Gateway. My configuration is shown below.

[Screenshot of Parameter Mapping configuration in my HTTP API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUj9W.png)

Edit: **I have discovered a problem here with this approach**: the HTTP API doesn't allow certain security-related headers to be added on the Parameter Mappings. I was trying to set header.x-amz-acl: 'bucket-owner-full-control' but I got the error message below:

> Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Operations on header x-amz-acl are restricted]

It seems that modifying any security-related S3 API header isn't possible in the HTTP API. This is a major problem for calling the S3 API directly as it means that in order to function, the S3 bucket needs to be public.